# How to Measuring Notifications delivery rate & CTR for Android where notification are sent through Amazon SNS and GCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I want to know how will i be able to track the following things when the notifications are sent to App through Amazon SNS and GCM?
1. Overall delivery rate[From the server till app] to the app , Delivery rate by type of notifications .
2. Failure reasons and its percentage
3. Click through rates of Notifications- On clicking notifications
4. Maximum / minimum no of notifications sent to a user per hour & per day
5. Average no of notifications sent to a user per hour & per day by platform
6. Delivery delay from the point of notification received till it reaches the user.
7. App launch via Notification click